# ¿Como filtrar un rango de fechas en Oracle?

Tags: plsql

Tengo la siguiente inquietud.

- El periodo fiscal empieza de Julio Actual
- Y finaliza en Julio del año próximo.

Por ejemplo:

- Inicio: JUL-21 (MM-YY)
- Fin:    JUN-22 (MM-YY)

Los datos de la tabla que me brindaron son:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces he hecho la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT  COLUMN_VALUE R FROM CUBES_LOV
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'BALANCE'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'PERIOD_NAME'
AND COLUMN_VALUE = 'JAN22-23' and COLUMN_VALUE = 'MAR22-23'
```

Y la consulta devuelve lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces convertí a fecha realizando la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT  COLUMN_VALUE FROM CUBES_LOV
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'BALANCE'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'PERIOD_NAME'
AND COLUMN_VALUE BETWEEN to_CHAR(TO_DATE('JAN22-23','MONYY-DD'),'MONYY') and  to_CHAR(TO_DATE('MAR22-23','MONYY-DD'),'MONYY')
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME ASC
```

Y devuelve lo mismo:
**Que la imagen anterior**

**¿Existirá alguna manera de filtrar por fecha fiscal?**

Comment: Saludos. Me da la impresión el detalle lo tienes por que conviertes de nuevo a **VARCHAR**; (de tu última consulta) déjalo en **TO_DATE**; no es lo mismo comparar CARACTERES que FECHA; por ejemplo **Abril** como caracter está antes de **Enero**, no así en fecha. Cosa a parte las validaciones/verificaciones que tenga que hacer por ejemplo con la fila que tiene **JUNADJ21-22** de los datos que muestras. Claro, igual **COLUMN_VALUE** aplica el **TO_DATE**

Answer (score 0):

Creo que vas bien con el BETWEEN. La tabla contiene fechas en formato VARCHAR2 y para operar con rangos de fechas debes transformar a DATE. Te sobra la doble transformación:

BETWEEN TO_DATE('JAN22-23','MONYY-DD') and  TO_DATE('MAR22-23','MONYY-DD')